# Does increasing the number of fields in JOIN statement increase/decrease the speed of execution?

Tags: sql

I have two tables with 3.5 million rows of data. I am creating a left join between the two to create a new view.

Code 1:

```
SELECT t1.c1,t1.c2,t2.c3,t2.c4
from table1 as t1 
   left join table2 as t2
   on t1.Location=t2.Location and t1.OrderNumber=t2.OrderNumber and t1.Customer=t2.Customer
```

Code 2:

```
SELECT t1.c1,t1.c2,t2.c3,t2.c4
from table1 as t1 
   left join table2 as t2
   on t1.OrderNumber=t2.OrderNumber
```

Both snippets of code give the same desired result as the Order number field in table 2 has only unique values.

Is it better to give more fields to JOIN compared to only one?

Comment: Choosing the database can have a big impact on performance.  I've removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: it depends on if those fields are indexed, if they have a foreign key relationship, what database you are using (among many, many other things).  I would imagine a single condition would be "faster" as you are only checking one thing.  Build both queries and use an explain query or something similar to test execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.c1,t1.c2,t2.c3,t2.c4
from table1 as t1 
left join table2 as t2
       on t1.Location    = t2.Location 
      and t1.OrderNumber = t2.OrderNumber 
      and t1.Customer    = t2.Customer
```

If OrderNumber is the PK of either table then adding additional fields will not change the results and it will not improve performance unless an index as not present on the other side.

If Order number field in table 2 has only unique values it would not change the query.  If it is a PK or has a unique constraint/index then addition fields would not help unless what Table2.OrderNumber was joined to was not indexed.